# How to combine two different strings in one string?

Tags: c#, string

I have checked most of the questions might contain my solution but I couldn't find any. Or maybe I didn't understand. So, here is my question:

I want to combine two strings in one and keep using it alone.

My strings:

```
    static string name = ""; (for example: John or Jane)
    static string gender = ""; (for example: Mr. or Mrs.)
```

and I want to combine these two in one like this:

```
    static string player = gender+name;

    Console.writeline("Hello "+player);
```

and I want to see it in my console like this:

```
 Hello Mr.John or Hello Mrs.Jane
```

I didn't want to mention console.readline parts. There will be entries where I will type name and gender.
Thanks

EDIT:

This is what I did (Sorry, it take too long):

```
    static string name = "";
    static string gender = "";
    static string player = name + gender;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome. What is your name?");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sex?\n-Male\n-Female");
        gender = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome"+player);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

These result like "Welcome **__**"

Comment: I don't see the problem...

Comment: You already did it - static string player = gender+name;

Comment: Yes. This doesn't work. I just wanted you to know what did I try before I post this.

Comment: If you want the data entered on the console, don't make your strings static.

Comment: the player string will be a result of gender and name, if you change your gender and name variables after you do `player = gender+name`, your player string will still contain the old values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that player should be a function, not a string.

```
String Player()
{
     return gender + name;
}
```

This has to be outside your main function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `player` is calculated at the class initialization. So basically you're combining `string.Empty` and `string.Empty`. `Player` is not calculated before each use.

So you could just do `player = name + gender;` before using it, but a good practice is to use variables restrained to the scope they're used in. Since you're name and gender are used in Main, use local variables.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name;
    string gender;

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome. What is your name?");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Sex?\n-Male\n-Female");
    gender = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + gender + name);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you prefer, you can also do

```
string player = gender + name;
Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + player);
```

but I think the intent was clear enough without the temp variable. If you need more complex formatting, you can also `string.Format`, it's cleaner than a bunch of `+` operators.

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Welcome, {0} {1}!", gender, name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You read `name` and `gender` but you never combine them after getting their value, so `player` still remains an empty string.

Do this, instead:

```
player = gender + name;
Console.WriteLine("Welcome "+player);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.ReadLine();
player = gender+name;
Console.WriteLine("Welcome"+player);
```

This will set the strings to what they have been read as.
You would also need an if statement to change fe/male to mr/s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Concat(string firstString,string secondString)`, if you want to merge strings with no delimiter. And you can use `String.Join(string separator, string[] stringsToBeJoined)`. The first parameter is the separator between strings in the merged single string and the second parameter is the array of strings which will be merged.